# How can I add multiple WHERE statements to a table join?

Tags: postgresql

I am querying a table called frames, each frame has many tags. I want to select only the frames that match 2 (or more) tags.

The below query will return only frames with the tags.name = 'foo'

```
    SELECT "frame"."id",
    "tags"."id" AS "tags.id", 
    "tags"."name" AS "tags.name"
    FROM "frames" AS "frame" 
    INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tags" 
    ON "frame"."id" = "tags"."frameId" 
    AND "tags"."name" = 'foo'
```

But if I also want to select frames that have 'foo' AND 'bar' this does not work, it returns an empty result.

```
    SELECT "frame"."id",
    "tags"."id" AS "tags.id", 
    "tags"."name" AS "tags.name"
    FROM "frames" AS "frame" 
    INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tags" 
    ON "frame"."id" = "tags"."frameId" 
    AND "tags"."name" = 'foo' 
    AND "tags"."name" = 'bar'
```

Comment: Think about `"tags"."name" = 'foo' AND "tags"."name" = 'bar'` - a single column can only contain a single value. It can't be equal to `foo` and `bar` at the same time

Comment: I think I know what you mean - one cell can't contain `foo` and `bar` at the same time. But the column can, I think? So the 'name' column might have `foo, bar, foo, bar` and the matching frameID column has `1,1,2,3`. So in this case I'm just trying to find frameID 1 as it matches both `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `OR` logic here, preferably in an explicit `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    f.id,
    t.id AS "tags.id", 
    t.name AS "tags.name"
FROM frames f
INNER JOIN tags t
    ON f.id = t.frameId
WHERE
    t.name IN ('foo', 'bar');
```